# Disable back functionality on Duplicate Window (asp code)

Tags: asp-classic

I have an application that requires a user to login.  Upon login, a key is stored in the database for that login session.

I am having an issue when the user does Ctrl+K because it opens a duplicate window, which is now sharing the key stored to the database.  I redirect them to the login page when they open a duplicate, but they are still allowed to click 'back' and they now have two windows with the same key - this causes MANY problems in my application...

How can I stop the user from going back - or how I can force login again (which creates a new key and both windows would then be valid) on any new window?

Thanks

Comment: As a rule of thumb: If native, built-in browser behavior breaks your application, then it's not the browser that needs to be fixed.

Comment: That may be true, however, this is a large application and I am only the newest programmer on it...  rewriting the whole application is not an option at this point.

Answer (score 0):

How are you detecting that they are opening a new window? When you redirect them, can't you simply set a flag in your database that indicates that their current session key is not longer valid? This way, they are really kicked out - and not simply redirected to a login page.

Comment: This is actually part of the problem I think.  We check for a new window with the http referer and window.name=''.  Most of the time, it catches it and redirects to the login, but sometimes it doesn't - but we don't want to invalidate their other window - so we don't want to kick them out.  We just don't want them to have two open windows for the same session/key.

Answer (score 0):

okay - found a different way to handle this using window.name.

Thanks anyway all.